# How to get the InnerHTML from lightning:inputRichText?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, html, inputrichtext

I want to get the full HTML out of the inputRichText component, or be able to recreate it. Essentially, I want to copy its contents exactly including the format and post it and send in an email elsewhere in its exact form. For example, in the pic below, I want to copy the list in its bulleted, bold, and italics form. There is a getFormat() method as described here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:inputRichText/specification

> Returns an object representing the formats of the currently selected
>   content. Only align, font, and size are supported.

Although I can't figure out how to properly use it, or if it will contain what I need.

[image: InputRichText Component]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value attribute should contain the HTML:

### JS:

```
import { LightningElement, track} from 'lwc';

export default class testLwc extends LightningElement {
    @track htmlValue;

    handleChange(event) {
        console.log(event.target.value);
    }
}
```

### Template

```
<template>
    <lightning-input-rich-text
        value={htmlValue}
        onchange={handleChange}>
    </lightning-input-rich-text>
</template>
```

### Output

[image: output]

### Output with List, bold and Italic:

[image: output2]